# Long Running Python Script in VSCode Exits with 'Polite quit request'

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have a long running Python script which is running in Visual Studio Code.

After a while the script stops running, there are no errors just this statement:

"fish: “/usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.…” terminated by signal SIGTERM (Polite quit request)"

What is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

If a process recieves SIGTERM, some other process sent that signal. That is what happened in your case.

The SIGTERM signal is sent to a process to request its termination. Unlike the SIGKILL signal, it can be caught and interpreted or ignored by the process. This allows the process to perform nice termination releasing resources and saving state if appropriate. SIGINT is nearly identical to SIGTERM.

SIGTERM is not sent automatically by the system. There are a few signals that are sent automatically like SIGHUP when a terminal goes away, SIGSEGV/SIGBUS/SIGILL when a process does things it shouldn't be doing, SIGPIPE when it writes to a broken pipe/socket, etc.

SIGTERM is the signal that is typically used to administratively terminate a process.

That's not a signal that the kernel would send, but that's the signal a process would typically send to terminate (gracefully) another process. It is sent by default by the `kill`, `pkill`, `killall`, `fuser -k` commands.

Possible reasons why your process recieved such signal are:

- *execution of the process takes too long*
- *insufficient memory or system resources to continue the execution of the process*

But these are some possibilities. In your case, the root of the issue might be related with something different. You can avoid from a SIGTERM signal by telling the procces to ignore the signal but it is not suggested to do.

Refer to this [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html) for more information.

Check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10231/when-does-the-system-send-a-sigterm-to-a-process) **similar** question for additional information.